# how to use Array class "partition" method

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm currently studying Array class in swift. I have encountered the following method

```
mutating func partition(by belongsInSecondPartition: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Int
```

But the [apple official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2294611-partition) does not have any explanation on what is method is and how it is used.

Why no explanation is provided for this method? Is this a exception or a lot of other functions doesn't have explanation as well? When encountering situations like this, what is the best way to deal with it (i.e. learning how to use the method)?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablecollection/2431340-partition

Comment: @Mr.Bista do you mind if I ask, why the "partition" method in array documentation does not have comments?

Comment: The latest [documentation of `MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/2905358-partition) states that it is currently in beta.